# End activity from fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to implement an onboard activity which shows only for the first time of using the app,
after it finished it will move to the main activity.

I've made another activity which includes fragments,
afterwards I'd like to set a settings on shared-preferences which hold a value that tells if it first time or not.

onboard activity:

```
class OnboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboard)
    }


    fun finishOnBoarding() {
        val preferences = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
        preferences.edit()
            .putBoolean("onboarding_complete", true).apply()
        val main = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(main)
        finish()
    }
}
```

InitialScreenFragment which is the last fragment in my code:

```
class InitialScreenFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentInitialScreenBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    lateinit var callback: FragmentActivity

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callback = requireActivity();
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentInitialScreenBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
//finish button which suppose to end the session of boarding
//      binding.finishBtn.setOnClickListener{
//            callback.finishOnBoarding()
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

how can I set the listener on finish button to call my activity method to end the onboard please?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use separate interface as callback

```
interface OnboardingListener {
  fun finishOnboarding()
}
```

implement this interface in your `OnboardActivity`

```
class OnboardActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnboardingListener  {

  override fun finishOnboarding(){
        val preferences = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("onboarding_complete", true).apply()
        val main = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(main)
        finish()
  }
}
```

and for example set it to fragment from your activity

```
class InitialScreenFragment : Fragment() {
.....
var callback: OnboardingListener? = null
.....
}

val fragment: InitialScreenFragment = InitialScreenFragment()
fragment.callback = this // this should be in OnboardActivity where you create an instance of InitialScreenFragment
```

and then from your fragment call

```
callback?. finishOnboarding()
```

Comment: Alternate and simpler solution on the Fragment side is to use `(activity as? OnboardingListener)?.finishOnboarding()` so you don't have to fool with having and setting a `callback` property. It would get tricky to ensure your `callback` property is always set, even after screen rotations and any possible Fragment transactions.

Comment: Yeah but this is much simpler, but I the way I described is much more dinamyc because there is separation of classes which makes code more readable. So it's up to you to use whatever you want.

Comment: I would argue this has less separation of concerns because the Activity has to know what the Fragment is doing and the Fragment has to know what the Activity is doing. There is a fair amount of code necessary in the Activity to ensure the callback is set after a Fragment transaction, like if that other Fragment shows a DialogFragment. With the Activity casting way of doing it, the Activity can remain ignorant of Fragment specifics.

Comment: Not Agree with - "the Fragment has to know what the Activity is doing". the fragment does not need to know what the activity is doing, his lifecycle is connected to the host activity lifecycle and that's enought for him, the same fragment can be used in different activities so he does not need to know whats going on in all activities. the one fragment can be used also in another fragment as a child fragment, and what's then ? He just need to have  an interface to close his host, whether it's activity or fragment. And also the same callback fun finishOnboarding may be implemented in diff. way